# What is the URL for the icon of a UWP app?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-store

Is there some URL for an app's icon on the Windows Store?

I want to link to it, so that if I update that icon, the image on my website will be automatically updated too.

(I'm asking because I think I saw that mentioned somewhere, though searching now, I can't find anything like that.)

Comment: If you really want to do so. Maybe you can parse the web page of you app detail to get the icon image url.

Comment: @ChrisShao Thanks. But I tried that before posting the question and saw that it looks like some very long guid. So I'm worried that it won't stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

In your app manifest, you must declare the icon/tiles of your app. They will be part of the app package and cannot be changed.

You can still send custom tile update to your application tile but that will never change the default tile/icon.

You can have a look at the appx manifest's [VisualElements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-visualelements) documentation for the logo, small logo etc images paths remarks:

> A string between 1 and 256 characters in length that ends with ".jpg", ".png", or ".jpeg" that can't contain these characters: <, >, :, %, ", |, ?, or *. In this string, the / and \ characters can't be the first or last characters. Also, the string can contain / or \ but not both.

Only local, package relative paths are allowed.

Comment: Those icons are then uploaded and appear on the Windows Store. See one way of referencing them in the first comment to my question. The question is is there an official URL which will always link to whatever updated icon is there at the time.